# Duvidas com um contador regressivo em JS e HTML

Tags: javascript, html, contador

imagino que essa minha duvida seja meio bobinha, mas é sério estou metade do dia tentando resolver esse desafio que me propus e infelizmente não consegui, lembrando que sou bem iniciante.

Pois bem, resolvi criar um cronometro usando JS, onde o usuário insere o tempo num input number HTML, o JS recebe o valor, converte para number, então o if subtrai 1 do valor a cada 1000 milissegundos e exibe no HTML.

Acontece que ele funciona se eu determino o valor fixo na variável time e coloco o onload chamando a função js na tag body. Mas usando o input number com o onclick chamando a função no botão ele só exibe o primeiro valor da contagem regressiva e trava. Estou empacado aí. Mais uma coisa, tentei colocar os input dentro de um form mas nesse caso ele só piscava o numero e sumia o valor.

```js
function contador(){
    let val = document.getElementById('valor');//essa variavel recebe o valor do form
    let time = Number(val.value);//essa variavel converte o valor recebido do form para numero
    
    if(time > 0){
        time = time -1;
        if(time == 0){
            time = "FIM!"
        }
    }

    tempo.innerText = time;
    setTimeout("contador()", 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contador regressivo!</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Digite abaixo um valor para o cronometro:</h1>
        <input type="number" name="valor" id="valor">
        <input type="submit" value="OK" onclick="contador()">
        <div id="tempo">Preparar!</div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que a cada segundo você está inicializando o `val` novamente. Aí dá a impressão que o loop não está funcionando, mas na verdade ele "funciona sempre com o mesmo valor"

Veja a diferença inicializando apenas uma vez (não é uma boa solução, é apenas para evidenciar o problema):

```js
var val; // Global apenas para ilustrar 
var time;

function inicia(){
    // VAMOS PEGAR O VALOR SO UMA VEZ
    val = document.getElementById('valor');//essa variavel recebe o valor do form
    time = Number(val.value);//essa variavel converte o valor recebido do form para numero
    setTimeout("contador()", 1000);
}

function contador(){
    // AGORA DECREMENTA, SEM PEGAR O VALOR INICIAL 
    if(time > 0){
        time = time -1;
        if(time == 0){
            time = "FIM!"
        }
    }

    tempo.innerText = time;
    setTimeout("contador()", 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contador regressivo!</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Digite abaixo um valor para o cronometro:</h1>
        <input type="number" name="valor" id="valor">
        <input type="submit" value="OK" onclick="inicia()">
        <div id="tempo">Preparar!</div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara, vlw por responder, com certeza vai ajudar em meus estudos!

Answer (score -1):

Bom, para fazer o cronômetro seria necessário utilizar o `setInterval()`, e você utilizou o `setTimeout()`.

O `setTimeout()` executa uma vez depois do tempo definido, enquanto o `setInterval()` executa infinitamente(ou pelo menos até que você pare ele com `clearInterval()`).

Mais informações em [NodeBR](http://nodebr.com/funcoes-temporizadoras-embutidas-no-javascript-settimeout-e-setinterval/)

Segue o código correto:

```
function iniciarContador(){
  const val = document.getElementById('valor');
  let time = Number(val.value) + 1;
  const contador = setInterval(() => {
    if (time > 0) 
      time = time - 1;
    else {
      time = "FIM!"
      console.log('Finished');
      clearInterval(contador);
    }
    tempo.innerText = time;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara, agradeço funcionou certinho, realmente me ajudou em meus estudos, vlw!